# Make an Android application using JUCE library

Tags: android

I would like to make an android application using JUCE libray. I am little bit new in android development, After lots of search on google but i can not getting proper idea of JUCE library, I want to use this library for change font in my android application, If any one have idea then please give some suggestion of this topic.
Thanks...